# Jmeter 4 | HTTP Request sampler JAVA implementation bytes sent not captured

Tags: jmeter

We are using JAVA implementation for one of the requests.In the request we are uploading a file. Request doesn't work when HTTPCLIENT4 implementation is selected.The request works fine with previous Jmeter version with HTTPCLIENT3.1 implementation. We need to capture bytes sent in results. How to capture bytes sent through JAVA implementation in HTTP Request sampler

Comment: You can't. Java implementation simply doesn't set that parameter. You can submit it as a bug to JMeter team. A better solution would be figuring out why HTTPCLIENT4 doesn't work for you. A (not very reliable) workaround is to get request headers, and check if it has `Content-Length` field. That field will tell you the size of the sent content, excluding headers. You can do it using JSR223 PostProcessor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Sent bytes` is basically a combination of URL + headers + body so you can calculate it yourself using [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and code like:

```
def url = sampler.getUrl().toString().length()
def headers = prev.getHeadersSize()
def body = 0;
sampler.getHTTPFiles().each {file ->
    body += new File(file.getPath()).length()
}

prev.setSentBytes(url + headers + body)
```

Where:

- `sampler` is an instance of [HTTPSamplerProxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerProxy.html) where you can get all files which you're sending with the request
- `prev` is an instance of [HTTPSampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSampleResult.html) where you can get URL and Headers and also override `Sent Bytes` field.

See [The Groovy Templates Cheat Sheet for JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-groovy-templates-cheat-sheet-for-jmeter) to see what else you can do with Groovy and how.